# Reverse looping a triangle problem deleting string character

Tags: javascript

```
for (let i = "#"; i.length < 10; i+="#"){
  console.log(i);
 
}
for (let y = "*********"; y.length >0; y-="*"){
    console.log(y);
}
```

The first part is  Eloquent JavaScript exercise. I wanted to make another loop starts from end of the first loop. The first loops ends with "########" and my other loop will start same amount of "#" but with "*" and it should decrease until it has one "*". So it would be reverse triangle like this:

```
#
##
**
*
```

I wanted to make it as simple as first loop. My question is can we make it like the first loop? And why "-=" is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not modify a string using `-=` operator. Use `y = y.slice(0, -1)` instead:

```js
for (let i = "#"; i.length < 10; i += "#") {
  console.log(i);

}
for (let y = "*********"; y.length > 0; y = y.slice(0, -1)) {
  console.log(y);
}
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)!